# Daphne. Access to Django defined objects

Tags: python, django, shared-memory, wss, daphne

I am using Django and channels (for WebSockets).
Earlier, when I was developing, I created some objects in memory when a user does a request, and then websockets can use these objects.

After, I run the production server with ssl, and for testing, I had to run apps separately: `python manage.py startsslserver` and `daphne ... project.asgi:application`.
And now sockets do not have access to objects, which are initialized in django server.

Anybody knows, how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed for a clear answer. django websocket problems are usually associated with other causes such as nginx.conf or daphne.service etc..

Comment: I use the default Django server with daphne, to run WebSockets. That's it.